Can't run python code with external libraries from docker container - "No module named" error
I have the docker file:
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN pip install \
    cryptography \
    bcrypt \
    pynacl \
    paramiko \
    scp \
    loguru \
    pydantic \
    psutil

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-h", "/etc/ssh/key"]
WORKDIR /code

And this main.py file import references:
import psutil
from loguru import logger
from paramiko import SSHClient
from pydantic import BaseModel
from scp import SCPClient

When running docker-compose with:
COMMAND='python main.py "hostname" 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,192.168.0.5' docker-compose up

I get this output:
infra-host_a-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
infra-host_a-1  |   File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
infra-host_a-1  |     from loguru import logger
infra-host_a-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loguru'
infra-host_a-1 exited with code 1

Docker-compose content:
version: "2.2"


services:
  host_a:
    build: build
    command: ${COMMAND}
    hostname: hostA
    ports:
    - "2222:22"
    volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    networks:
      net1:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.100.1
  host_b:
    build: build
    hostname: hostB
    networks:
      net1:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.100.2
      net2:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.200.1
  host_c:
    build: build
    hostname: hostC
    networks:
      net1:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.100.3
      net3:
        ipv4_address: 172.29.100.1
networks:
  net1:
    driver: bridge
    enable_ipv6: false
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 10.10.100.0/24
        gateway: 10.10.100.32

This only happens with docker-compose, but when running the project in a container alone it works with docker build/run.
How do I solve this?

Did you install loguru module on the right path? check it from import sys and print(sys.path). Try resolving whether the modules are on the path or the path that you want are there.

Did you make sure docker-compose rebuilds the image?

yes I did. I used --force-recreate flag with the command

The overall setup here seems to be fairly indirect.  If you COPY your code into the image, set the image's CMD to run the process and not an ssh daemon, and just docker run the resulting image, do you have the same import problem in this simpler setup?

I solved the issue by using --build with docker compose like this:
docker-compose up --build

This made the libraries installation valid
